# How do I fix(lock) my image-model on vuforia AR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to fix my image on the screen and I need to do this with a button in AR. So I am trying to stop AR behaviour when users select to stop tracking (with UI button). Basically I want to lock the model once it loaded if users click the lock button.

Desired behaviour : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVXcZcl4nj4

Comment: Good luck! what have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: @yakobom I simply tried to Disable Tracking with the codes that I found on net. But they didnt work. I think I have to change the parent from my image target to AR camera. What do you think?

Comment: What I think is very simple - if people will see the code that didn't work, they may be able to suggest how to fix it. You are not utilizing the assistance you can get here if you don't supply the full information.